# Выравнивание изображения внутри блока

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/c2_btn.png" alt="" 
          width="35" height="35"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/home_btn.png" alt="" width="35" 
          height="35"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/c3_btn.png" alt="" width="35" 
          height="35"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
  background: #212121;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы изображения внутри col, были выровнены по центру блока?

---

Пробовал добавлять  класс "img-fluid center-block" и "img-responsive center-block" Но ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.menu {
  background: #212121;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
text-align:center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/220px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="35"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/220px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="35"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg/220px-Hopetoun_falls.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="35"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Господи, невероятно )))

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при "@media (min-width: 576px)" колонки становились типа "col-"?

Comment: Не совсем вас понял. Вам нужно изменить свойство при минимальной ширине 576px или изменить значение **class**?

Comment: Прошу прощения, кажется я понял, нужно просто найти свойства "col-" и применить их в медиа запросе.

Comment: А вообще да, как изменить значение class?

Comment: Для начала узнайте на JS ширину экрана, а потом используйте attr в JQuery. Если не разберетесь, то могу написать

Comment: Спасибо, не заморачивайтесь, я понял

Answer (score 0):

Картинка будет выравняться и по **ВЫСОТУ**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.col {
  outline: 1px solid #f00;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="menu">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
           <a href="#"><img src="img/img-for-testing.jpg" alt="error-img" width="35" height="35"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <a href="#"><img src="img/img-for-testing.jpg" alt="error-img" width="35" height="35"></a>
         </div>
         <div class="col">
           <a href="#"><img src="img/img-for-testing.jpg" alt="error-img" width="35" height="35"></a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```